# Write a loop for hexadecimal HTML colors

Tags: color, loops, html

I need to define 256 pixel colors in HEX values like this:

> \definecolor{pixel 1}{HTML}{000000} 
>   ...
>   \definecolor{pixel 256}{HTML}{FFFFFF}

Can I do that in a form of a simple loop? How?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You can define the 256 grey shades from black to white using the `forloop` package like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{loop}
\forloop{loop}{0}{\value{loop}<256}{\definecolor{pixel \arabic{loop}}{RGB}{\arabic{loop},\arabic{loop},\arabic{loop}}}

\begin{document}

\forloop[10]{loop}{0}{\value{loop}<256}{\textcolor{pixel \arabic{loop}}{pixel~\arabic{loop}} }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing this: \foreach \name/\n in {0,...,255}{
\pgfmathsetmacro\k{\n*0.004}
 \xglobal\definecolor{pixel \name}{gray}{\k}
}